# Which postgres data type should I use for large XML message come from network?

Tags: xml, database, postgresql

I have incoming xml which is potentially as big as 5M and I need to store it it with postgres 9.1. Which data type should I use ?

```
bytea 
character varying
text
```

or something else ?

BTW The xml itself contains some binary data in base64 format, does that make any difference when choosing data type in postgres ?

Thank

Comment: `xml` maybe? Definitely not `bytea` as that is for **binary** data, varchar and text are effectively the same thing in Postgres (as documented in the manual).

Comment: The xml itself contains some binary data encoded in base64 format, does that make any difference?

Comment: XML is text (strings) you cannot have "real" binary data in it. Everything in there is represented as a String.

Comment: base64 encoded data is text. So no difference.

Comment: But the fact the String can be as big as 5M in size would it be storing bytea have certain advantage ? Can xml or char varying cope with 5M long string effectively (load and save)?

Comment: Internall storage mechanics (TOAST) is the same for `XML`, `TEXT`, `VARCHAR` and `BYTEA`. There are no advantages of storing XML as `BYTEA`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`. It will allow you to store and retrieve your XML file from DB. But nothing more.
2. `XML` . Will allow you to store, retrieve, validate, edit, search ... the XML files, but may (or may not) involve some overhead on storing files to DB.

There is no reason to store XML files as `BYTEA` at all. 5 MB size is nothing special for Postgres. In my last project I worked strings with up to 0.5 GB length in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and you stored the 0.5G length string with Text or VarChar and works fine?

Comment: @Gob00st There were some problems on driver level, when storing 100+ MB varchar to DB. There were no problems with 5-10 MB strings.

Comment: Thanks mine is 5 upper limit so should be fine.